# Angularjs best practise - $scope vs this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to follow best practise but have a problem understanding when to use $scope and when to use 'this'.  I have a simple example using angularjs 1.4.8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
<title>Test button action</title>
<script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./testBtn.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
        <button ng-click="testBtn()">test button</button>
        {{testResult}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Test1Ctrl as test1">
        <select ng-model="chosen" ng-change="getDetails(chosen)">
            <option value='option1'>Option1</option>
            <option value='option2'>Option2</option>
            <option value='option3'>Option3</option>
        </select>
        <p>You choose {{test1Result}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The testBtn.js file looks like this

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("testApp", []);
    angular.module("testApp").controller("TestCtrl", testCtrl);
    angular.module("testApp").controller("Test1Ctrl", test1Ctrl);
    function testCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.testBtn = testBtn;
        function testBtn() {
            if (this.testResult == '' || this.testResult == null) {
                this.testResult = "Button clicked";
            } else {
                this.testResult = '';
            }
        }
    }
    function test1Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.getDetails = getDetails;
        function getDetails(opt) {
            this.test1Result = opt;
        }
    }
})();
```

This works fine as it stands.  However if I change the two functions to say 
`this.testBtn = testBtn;` and `this.getDetails = getDetails;` clicking the button or choosing an option doesn't work and no errors are shown in the console log.

Why doesn't 'this' work in these examples?  Would there have been a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `ng-click="testBtn()"`, angular will by default go and look for `testBtn` function in `$scope` object of the controller. Therefore, if you have not defined above function as `$scope.testbtn = function()...`, angular will not do any operation as function is not defined.

In `as` syntax of controller, function/models are defined using `this` scope of the controller. Best practice for using `this` is to store it at the first line of controller in a variable so that you wont fall into any scope conflicts.

```
angular.module("testApp").controller("Test1Ctrl", test1Ctrl);
    function testCtrl($scope) {
        var ctrlScope = this;
        ctrlScope.testBtn = function() {
            if (ctrlScope.testResult == '' || ctrlScope.testResult == null) {
                ctrlScope.testResult = "Button clicked";
            } else {
                ctrlScope.testResult = '';
            }
        }
    }

<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
    <button ng-click="test.testBtn()">test button</button>
    {{test.testResult}}
</div>
```

"as" syntax makes the code more readable in my opinion and also take care of name conflicts if controllers are nested.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation.  I've now been able to eliminate $scope from my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use test and test1 controllerAs in view as well. Then you must use `this` in controller. Advantage: Nested controllers with same model names.

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
    <button ng-click="test.testBtn()">test button</button>
    {{test.testResult}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="Test1Ctrl as test1">
    <select ng-model="test1.chosen" ng-change="test1.getDetails(test1.chosen)">
        <option value='option1'>Option1</option>
        <option value='option2'>Option2</option>
        <option value='option3'>Option3</option>
    </select>
    <p>You choose {{test1.test1Result}}</p>
</div>
```

`$scope` is used when your controller is bind to a route like `ng-route` module or state like ui-router.

Comment: "$scope is used when your controller is bind to a route like ng-route module or state like ui-router." Why can't I use $scope without ng-route or state? Why was the edit made that I must use 'this' keyword with controllerAs sytax?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `vm` for `controllerAs` variable.

John Papa has a great publication about it and for me and my team it became something like a good practice.

[AngularJS's Controller As and the vm Variable](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

The main advantages:

> 1. Provides a consistent and readable method of creating bindings in my controllers
> 2. Removes any issues of dealing with this scoping or binding (i.e. closures in nested functions)
> 3. Removes $scope from the controller unless I explicitly need it for something else
> 4. Makes me happy since its short :)

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript is very generic and it is referring to self-refrence for current object, but in AngularJs to share anything between controller and html you have to share it thru $scope, actually your code is registering "testBtn" first in `$scope.testBtn = testBtn;` then implementation in `function testBtn()` to understand it let me rewrite it here :

```
$scope.testBtn = this.testBtn;
this.testBtn = function() {}
```

> javascript languge will not face any ordering problems, and will understand it as:

```
this.testBtn = function() {}
$scope.testBtn = this.testBtn;
```

inside your function `this` will refer to object that you function inside which is `$scope` so anything inside  `$scope` you can access by this inside function only as it is registered in `$scope` already.

my recommendation for you to use `$scope` and don't use this to not be confused, also no need for registering then implementation you can do it in one step, it is confusing, here I'm rewriting your controller:

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.testBtn = function () {
        if ($scope.testResult == '' || $scope.testResult == null) {
            $scope.testResult = "Button clicked";
        } else {
            $scope.testResult = '';
        }
    }
}
```